# sql import export wizard dropping data during upload

Tags: sql-server, excel

As part of month end process we upload a few csv files onto SQL Server 2014. We've found that converting the csv files into Excel Binary Workbook makes it quicker to upload the files using SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data Wizard (32 bit). For some reason this month one of the files is dropping critical data from one of the fields. About 16k records out of 325k are being dropped from just one field. There is no error generated during the process. We've tried to trim the field before upload but didn't work. Has anybody faced a similar issue? How can we rectify this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can add some sample data and also the configuration details of what you set in SQL import and export.

Comment: Do you know if it's in the conversion to binary or the SQL loading process?  Might be in the conversion process if Excel is assuming a datatype?